# How to disable the screensaver password for all users via command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, windows-registry, screensaver

I have a pool of ~40 terminals running Windows Embedded POSReady (basically, a modified Windows XP). My problem is that these computers requires a password after exiting the screensaver.

The objective is to disable this behavior via the command line (batch), for easier deployment. I know how to disable this for one user (the current user) :

```
Reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaverIsSecure /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
```

But I wanted to know if it is possible to disable it for **all** users of the computer.

Comment: Could this be used a as a **startup script** for all users. That would help i assume.

Comment: Yeah but to set this startup script I have to log in all user accounts, which is not applicable

Comment: Hope this helps [Assign computer startup scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779329(v=ws.10).aspx)